# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null dotnet core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, facebook-oauth, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to setup Facebook authentication with dot-net core 2.0, but in my ExternalLoginCallbackAsync method, I'm always getting null as a response I have followed the documentation and so far this is what I've done:

> in my ConfigureServices in the startup file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
            options => options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(
    f => {
        f.AppId = Configuration["facebook-app-id"];
        f.AppSecret = Configuration["facebook-app-secret"];
});
```

in my login controller:

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
        {

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallbackAsync", "Login")                
            };
            return Challenge(authProperties,provider);
        }
```

in my ExternalLoginCallbackAsync method 
when I do

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

any hint why am I always getting null?

thanks

Comment: You can look at line 555 in the [SignInManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs) for the different conditions for when it returns null. 

For me it was because MS need to have their "NameIdentifier" claim, wich is basicly the same as sub claim. To fix this i added a ClaimAction to map sub to NameIdentifier.

Comment: thanks after you pointed in the right direction I figure it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at the  SignInManager code as  Lasse Vabe Rolstad suggested and for me, a key was missing in the auth properties so I had to add it manually like this:

```
 var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
 {
     RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallbackAsync", "Login"),
     Items = { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LoginProvider",provider) }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to enable SSL, once I enabled SSL it returned info correctly, to enable SSL, right click on the project --> properties --> Debug --> check (Enable SSL) in web server strings section. I'm using core 3.0