# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

I want to connect to GitHub using OAuth in aspnet core 2.0. I have the following setup.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
        );

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(new HtmlOutputFormatter()));
        services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGitHub(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/callback/GitHub");
        })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{provider}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string provider)
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Url.Action("CallBack", "Auth") }, provider);
    }

[HttpGet("callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CallBack()
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); // <== this is always NULL
        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

The auth flow gets completed correctly and without errors. However, the line

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

always yields null.

There are some leads scattered around the web, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852188/getexternallogininfoasync-returns-null-dotnet-core-2-0), bit none seem to scratch my itch.

Thoughts? Am I missing a setting somewhere? Probably...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see what is coming down the wire?

Comment: Not exactly. But the 'User.Identity.Name' is filled with the username and the correct Claims as well. So, somewhere, asp.net must be getting the info...

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852188/getexternallogininfoasync-returns-null-dotnet-core-2-0

Comment: @Elfocrash Not sure I'd call that a dupe, I'm betting the solution for Github IDP won't be the same as Facebook, but the suggestion to review the [`SignInManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs) source to figure out how and when it returns `null` is certainly a useful lead.

Comment: It's not a dupe. I also linked to it from the original question. @McGuireV10 I tried the same solution mentioned there. No luck...

Comment: I don't think you need to call `AddAuthentication` or `AddCookie` when you use `AddIdentity` unless you want to alter certain default options. (My auth doesn't use ASP.NET Identity or EF but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#cookie-based-authentication) part of the docs lead me to believe `AddIdentity` handles that for you.)

Answer (score 1):

when using with identityserver4, in the following part of code `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` was not matching and hence "auth" was `null`.

However, changing it to `idsrv.external` keeps it going.

```
 public async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(string expectedXsrf = null)
    {
        var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        var items = auth?.Properties?.Items;
        if (auth?.Principal == null || items == null || !items.ContainsKey("LoginProviderKey"))
```